# Relacionar itens de um array recursivamente com PHP

Tags: php

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma função nativa do PHP para relacionar todos os items de arrays com todos os itens de outros arrays, exemplo:

```
$arr['a'] = [1,2,3];
$arr['b'] = [4,5];
$arr['c'] = [7,8,9,10];
```

Para obter o seguinte resultado:

```
$result[] = [1,4,7];
$result[] = [1,4,8];
$result[] = [1,4,9];
$result[] = [1,4,10];
$result[] = [1,5,7];
$result[] = [1,5,8];
```

E por ai vai, até que todos tenham se relacionado, sendo que os arrays iniciais podem variar de numero bem como seus conteudos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não achei nada nativo mas resolvi desta forma, funcionou pra mim!

```
    $arr_ovp = [ 'Cor'      => ['White','Black','Green','Blue','Red'],
                 'Tamanho'  => ['G','XG','XXL','XXG'],
                 'Manga'    => ['Curta','Cumprida','SemManga'],
                 'Estampa'  => ['Breaking Bad','Back to the Future','Star Wars']];



foreach($arr_ovp as $variacoes) {

    if( empty($arr1) ) {
        foreach($variacoes as $variacao) {
            $arr1[] = $variacao;
        }
    } else {
        foreach($arr1 as $opcao) {
            foreach($variacoes as $variacao) {
                $arr2[] = $opcao.' - '.$variacao;
            }
        }
        $arr1 = $arr2;
        $arr2 = '';
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr1);
exit;
```

Comment: "Relacionar itens de um array recursivamente" - A sua solução não é recursiva.

Comment: Realmente não é recursiva, mas resolveu pra mim, faz recursivo ai e cola aqui! vlw.